# Re-open this question?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, duplicates

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93923/is-it-unethical-for-me-to-not-tell-my-employer-i-finish-my-job-in-10hrs-per-week) has undergone some serious revision since is was marked as a duplicated. While I agree the question sounds similar to the dup, let me explain why I believe it should be re-opened.

1. His contract does not state hours of work
2. OP is an exempt employee meaning they collect a salary rather than paid per hour
3. OP is actually doing more work that what was asked of him in this case, where in the dup, OP did not do anything more than the 1 thing he was assigned
4. There is no question of dishonesty or inserting bugs into anything (which was a main component of the dup)
5. OP is still available to work when asked. In the dup, OP was out with his son

In light of these facts, I think it should be reopened. Because he is paid as a salary worked with no defined working hours, I believe that itself is just cause for reopening.

Comment: Varying details don't matter for duplicates, the whole point of Q&A is that answers are useful to the general situation. And there's also the fact that this is about Academia which often plays by its own rules and we traditionally direct people to [academia.se] for those. Would answers to this really be materially different?

Comment: In the dup question, it says that OP works full time 40 hours a week, so is lying to his employer. In this question, there is no mention of time and no lying to employer. I would say these are different questions. One is "can I lie to my employer about my hours" and the other is "must I report my hours if I am paid by salary". Maybe there is a dup out there that fits this questions, but I don't think this is it.

Comment: We don't look at the spirit of the question, we look at what the question actually says. And right now I really don't see how they're fundamentally different.

Comment: The answers should be dramatically different, I would think that makes it a different a question. The reason we mark things as duplicate is because the answer should already exist on another question. If those answers do not suffice, then the question is reopened. Because of the very different contracts, the answers themselves should be different.

Comment: "*The reason we mark things as duplicate is because the answer should already exist on another question*" Not really. A question is considered a duplicate if the linked "parent" question *could* have answers that cover it. While there is a questionable requirement for duplicate flags to point to a question that has at least one answer, the meta consensus as far as I've seen and remember is that there is no requirement for the linked question to adequately answer the closed question. The flag requirement doesn't affect Workplace much as we have virtually no unanswered questions on the site.

Comment: Anyhow, speaking as a user, the question in its current state is way too long and chaotic for me to even consider reading it, let alone casting an open vote. If you really think this question adds value to the site then I suggest heavily editing it to present a clear problem that's distinct from the linked question and that's on-topic. I'm not sure it's possible given the ultimately similar scenarios *and* the Academic angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still a "What should I do?" question.

Is it ethical or not is only constructive if you take it to the implied question of should I tell my employer what I have been doing?  - or - My employee is doing this do I need to correct it?  Those are off topic.

The philosophical question does not belong here.

This back doors into what code of personal ethics that you have do you feel I should use to evaluate?  Which is clearly asking for opinions...

I agree it is no longer a duplicate... and maybe never really was. That does not mean it should be reopened.

Comment: That makes sense  I just figured if noone closed the other question it must be on topic right?

Comment: @SaggingRufus it is not closed only because a mod decided to throw a bounty on it... i believe